# Arduino — Свет не прекращает моргать при нажатии на 0

Tags: c, arduino

Есть код , который при нажатии клавиши 1 включает свет , а при нажатии 0  выключает. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии 1 , свет начинал моргать , а при нажатии на 0 -- переставал . Код для микроконтроллера от Arduino

```
int val;
int LED = 12;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
 }

void loop() {
   if (Serial.available()){
    val = Serial.read();
      if (val == '1'){
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      }

      if ( val == '0'){
       digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      }
    }
  }
```

Так выглядит версия, которую сделал я , но она не прекращает моргать при нажатии на 0.

```
int val;
int LED = 12;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
 }

void loop() {
   if (Serial.available()){
    (val = Serial.read()) { 
        while (val == '1'){
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        delay(500); 
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        delay(500);
      }

  if (val == '0'){
       digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
   }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73009/discussion-on-question-by-max-litvinov-arduino------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неверно написан цикл. И вообще не понятно зачем он? если я все правильно понял, то `loop` вызывается автоматически?

Попробуйте так:

```
int val;
int LED = 12;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        val = Serial.read();
        while(val != '0') // проверим, не 0?
        {
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
            val = Serial.read();
        }

        if (val == '0')
        {
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В этом случае, свет моргает один раз и сразу гаснет

Comment: но если вводить не 1, а 111 , то моргать будет 3 раза

Comment: @MaxLitvinov: Пробуйте исправленную версию

Comment: Всё работает , только теперь он начинает моргать  сразу (без нажатия кнопки 1) , но когда отключаешь , снова включается нажатием 1. Как можно исправить, чтобы она не начинала моргать сразу, как только включается?

Comment: Логично. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @MaxLitvinov: ответ был обновлен, пожалуйста, если вам дали ответ, старайтесь хоть что-то сделать сами.

Comment: Обновленная версия моргает один раз при нажатии 1 и всё :(

Comment: @MaxLitvinov: В таком случае установите `-1` для `val` на старте программы. Добавьте еще 1 переменную `int`, заносите в нее полученные данные, сравнивайте их, если было последнее полученное 0, то ничего не делаем в цикле, т.е. не заходим в него. Просто логически подумайте как это должно быть, и попробуйте реализовать.

Comment: Понял. Буду пробовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть я для Arduino ни разу не писал, но тут видно, что у вас первый цикл (мигания) устроен так: `while (val == '1')`. Если вы нажмете на 0, то значение этой переменной не изменится, так как для этого нужно вызывать функцию `val = Serial.read()`. То есть решение - обновлять переменную `val`

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличная библиотека для индикации состояний при помощи светодиода. Называется [LEDseq](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ledseq/). Также понадобится библиотека [VEduino](https://sourceforge.net/projects/veduino).

```
#include <ve_avr.h>    // Use VEduino library
#include <LEDseq.h>    // Use LEDseq library

#define LEDPIN   12

const char state0[] = "22222223";           // (19*4ms ON, 19*4ms OFF) * 3 times, 19*4ms ON, OFF and stop 
const char *states[1] = { state0 };         // 1 state
const short delays[2] = { 19, -1 };         // 2 delays ('2' and '3')
const char stateChars[2] = { '2', '3' };    // Characters that used 

LEDseq led(LEDPIN,     // LED pin number.
       states,         // Sequences of states
       1,              // Count of states
       delays,         // Delays
       2,              // Count of delays
       stateChars,     // Characters that used
       0);             // Previously defined LEDseq object

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
     char ch = Serial.read();
     if (ch == '1')
        led.setState(0);
     else if (ch == '0')
        led.ledOff();
  }
  LEDseq::loop();
}
```